# is it possible to ignore date and check only time in this mongoose aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to search time between two time ranges disregarding the date (year,day,month) do not matter only time

I was able to reach to this point by myself but was not able to find any solution to consider only time unless I change my schema

```
StoreModel.aggregate([
      { $unwind: { path: "$practitioners" } },
      {
        $match: {
          _id: new Types.ObjectId(storeId),
          "practitioners._id": new Types.ObjectId(practitionerId),
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: false,
          timings: "$practitioners.schedule.timings",
        },
      },
      {
        $set: {
          dateInTimings: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                my_date: date,
              },
              in: {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$timings",
                  initialValue: false,
                  in: {
                    $cond: [
                      { $not: ["$$value"] },
                      {
                        $and: [
                          {
                            $gte: ["$$my_date", "$$this.from"],
                          },
                          {
                            $lte: ["$$my_date", "$$this.to"],
                          },
                        ],
                      },
                      "$$value",
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- use `$hour,$minute,$seconds` ignore the `year/month/day`
- compare `[hours1,minutes1,milliseconds1] > [hours2,minutes2,milliseconds2]` it will compare the members from left to right for the 2 dates

*i think this works as a way to compare only the times of 2 dates, but maybe a faster or simpler way exists

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6284270e853f039c69b0f8e1)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":{"date1":ISODate("2022-05-17T22:50:44.501Z")}},
 {"$set":{"date2":ISODate("2022-05-17T22:49:44.501Z")}},
 {"$set":
   {"date1Bigger":
     {"$gt":
       [[{"$hour":"$date1"}, {"$minute":"$date1"},
           {"$millisecond":"$date1"}],
         [{"$hour":"$date2"}, {"$minute":"$date2"},
           {"$millisecond":"$date2"}]]}}}])
```